# Trajectory optimization on custom quadrotor system - NaN detected during differentiation

Tags: python, c++, drake

I have attempted to simulate the effect of wind disturbance on a quadrotor in Drake by building quadrotor plant using Drake's `Wing`, `Propeller` and `MultiBodyPlant`  classes along with a custom `Spatial_Force_Concatinator` class that combines the forces coming from the `Propeller` and `Wing` and applies them to the "applied_aptial_force" port of the quadrotor `MultiBodyPlant`.

The system behaves as expected during simulation, the forces from the `Wing` and `Propeller` seem to be applied to the body correctly. However when I attempt to run perform trajectory optimization, there are NaNs detected during differentiation.

A minimal runnable reproduction of the code is below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from pydrake.all import (
    AbstractValue, AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph,ConstantVectorSource, BasicVector,BallRpyJoint,
    DiagramBuilder,DirectCollocation, DirectTranscription, MathematicalProgram, QuadraticCost,
    BoundingBoxConstraint, LinearConstraint,Cost, Constraint,LinearEqualityConstraint,FirstOrderTaylorApproximation,
    FiniteHorizonLinearQuadraticRegulatorOptions, FindResourceOrThrow, LinearSystem, Linearize, 
    LeafSystem_,ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce_, LeafSystem,ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce, 
    LogVectorOutput, MultibodyPlant, MakeFiniteHorizonLinearQuadraticRegulator, MultibodyPlant,
    MathematicalProgram, MeshcatVisualizerParams, MeshcatVisualizerCpp, Parser, PortDataType,
    plot_system_graphviz, Propeller, PropellerInfo, PiecewisePolynomial, RandomSource, 
    RandomDistribution, PrismaticJoint, RigidBody, RigidTransform, Role, RotationMatrix, 
    SceneGraph, Simulator, Solve, StartMeshcat, SpatialInertia, SolverOptions, CommonSolverOption,
    TrajectorySource, Trajectory, TimeStep, UnitInertia, VectorSystem, TemplateSystem, UnitInertia, eq)

from pydrake.multibody.plant import Wing

# Start the visualizer (run this cell only once, each instance consumes a port)
meshcat = StartMeshcat()


@TemplateSystem.define("SpatialForceConcatinator_")
def SpatialForceConcatinator_(T):
    class Impl(LeafSystem_[T]):
        def _construct(self, N_props, N_wings, converter = None):
            LeafSystem_[T].__init__(self, converter)
            # define list of AbstractValue spatial forces used to define propeller for

            self.N_props = N_props
            self.N_wings = N_wings

            self.DeclareAbstractInputPort("propeller_force",
                AbstractValue.Make([ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce_[T](), ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce_[T](), 
                ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce_[T](), ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce_[T]()]) )

            self.DeclareAbstractInputPort("wing_force",
                AbstractValue.Make([ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce_[T]()]) )

            self.DeclareAbstractOutputPort("spatial_forces", 
                lambda: AbstractValue.Make([ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce_[T]() for i in range(N_props + N_wings)]),
                self.OutputForces)

        def _construct_copy(self, other, converter=None):
            Impl._construct(self, other.N_props, other.N_wings, converter=converter)

        def OutputForces(self, context, output):
            prop_input_port = self.get_input_port(0)
            wing_input_port = self.get_input_port(1)

            propeller_force = prop_input_port.Eval(context)
            wing_force = wing_input_port.Eval(context)
            
            # concatenate all forces into a single list of forces
            output.set_value(propeller_force + wing_force)

            # for force in output.get_value():
                # print(f"output_force = {force}")

    return Impl

# Default instantations
SpatialForceConcatinator = SpatialForceConcatinator_[None]


def AddFloatingRpyJoint(plant, frame, instance):
    inertia = UnitInertia.SolidSphere(1.0)
    x_body = plant.AddRigidBody(
        "x", instance,
        SpatialInertia(mass=0, p_PScm_E=[0., 0., 0.], G_SP_E=inertia))
    plant.AddJoint(
        PrismaticJoint("x", plant.world_frame(), x_body.body_frame(),
                       [1, 0, 0]))
    y_body = plant.AddRigidBody(
        "y", instance,
        SpatialInertia(mass=0, p_PScm_E=[0., 0., 0.], G_SP_E=inertia))
    plant.AddJoint(
        PrismaticJoint("y", x_body.body_frame(), y_body.body_frame(),
                       [0, 1, 0]))
    z_body = plant.AddRigidBody(
        "z", instance,
        SpatialInertia(mass=0, p_PScm_E=[0., 0., 0.], G_SP_E=inertia))
    plant.AddJoint(
        PrismaticJoint("z", y_body.body_frame(), z_body.body_frame(),
                       [0, 0, 1]))
    plant.AddJoint(BallRpyJoint("ball", z_body.body_frame(), frame))


def create_quadrotor(quadrotor_builder, world_plant, scene_graph, obstacles  ):

    for obs in obstacles:
        obs.connect_obstacle_to_world(world_plant, scene_graph)

    #### Define quadrotor MultiBodyPlant using Quadrotor .urdf and Propeller class
    quad_model= Parser(world_plant).AddModelFromFile("/work/Quadrotor_MPC/quadrotor.urdf")
    quad_body = world_plant.GetBodyByName("base_link", quad_model)
    quad_frame = world_plant.GetFrameByName("base_link")

    ###### Change coordinates from quaternion to rpy ######
    AddFloatingRpyJoint(world_plant, quad_frame, quad_model)

    #finalize the world plant
    world_plant.Finalize()

    p1_thrust_ratio = 1.0
    p1_moment_ratio = 0.0245
    prop1_pose = RigidTransform(p=[.1750,0,0])
    p2_thrust_ratio = 1.0
    p2_moment_ratio = -0.0245
    prop2_pose = RigidTransform(p=[0,.1750,0])
    p3_thrust_ratio = 1.0
    p3_moment_ratio = 0.0245
    prop3_pose = RigidTransform(p=[-.1750,0,0])
    p4_thrust_ratio = 1.0
    p4_moment_ratio = -0.0245
    prop4_pose = RigidTransform(p=[0,-.1750,0])

    prop1 = PropellerInfo(quad_body.index(), prop1_pose, p1_thrust_ratio, p1_moment_ratio);
    prop2 = PropellerInfo(quad_body.index(), prop2_pose, p2_thrust_ratio, p2_moment_ratio);
    prop3 = PropellerInfo(quad_body.index(), prop3_pose, p3_thrust_ratio, p3_moment_ratio);
    prop4 = PropellerInfo(quad_body.index(), prop4_pose, p4_thrust_ratio, p4_moment_ratio);

    props = quadrotor_builder.AddSystem(Propeller([prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4]))

    
    fluid_density  = 1.225 # kg/m^3,  fluid density of air
    surface_area = 0.144 # m^2, calculated based on dimensions of quadrotor body
    wing_pose = RigidTransform(p=[0,0,0])
    wing = quadrotor_builder.AddSystem(Wing(quad_body.index(), surface_area, wing_pose,  fluid_density))

    # add force concatinator system to combine the forces from propeller and wing and apply them to the 
    # quadrotor body
    num_props = 4
    num_wings = 1
    force_concatinator = quadrotor_builder.AddSystem(SpatialForceConcatinator(num_props, num_wings))

    quadrotor_builder.Connect(props.get_spatial_forces_output_port(),
                    force_concatinator.get_input_port(0));

    quadrotor_builder.Connect(wing.get_spatial_force_output_port(),
                    force_concatinator.get_input_port(1));

    quadrotor_builder.Connect(force_concatinator.get_output_port(0),
                            world_plant.get_applied_spatial_force_input_port())

    quadrotor_builder.Connect(world_plant.get_body_poses_output_port(), 
                    props.get_body_poses_input_port())       

    quadrotor_builder.Connect(world_plant.get_body_poses_output_port(), 
                    wing.get_body_poses_input_port())      

    quadrotor_builder.Connect(world_plant.get_body_spatial_velocities_output_port(), 
                    wing.get_body_spatial_velocities_input_port())      


    quadrotor_builder.ExportInput(props.get_command_input_port(), "prop_command")
    quadrotor_builder.ExportInput(wing.get_wind_velocity_input_port(), "wind_velocity")
    quadrotor_builder.ExportOutput(world_plant.get_state_output_port(), "state")


    # Set up visualization in MeshCat
    meshcat.Delete()
    meshcat.ResetRenderMode()
    meshcat.SetProperty('/Background','visible',False)
    visualizer = MeshcatVisualizerCpp.AddToBuilder(quadrotor_builder, scene_graph, meshcat)
    # end setup for visualization

    built_quadrotor = quadrotor_builder.Build()


    context = world_plant.CreateDefaultContext()
    print(f"tau_g =  {world_plant.CalcGravityGeneralizedForces(context)}")
    num_vel = world_plant.num_velocities()
    print(f"num vel = {num_vel}")
    M = world_plant.CalcMassMatrix(context)
    print(f"Mass Matrix = {M}")
    Cv = world_plant.CalcBiasTerm(context)
    print(f"Cv= {Cv}")


    print(f"input port 0 data type = {built_quadrotor.get_input_port(0).get_data_type()}")
    print(f"input port 0 size = {built_quadrotor.get_input_port(0).size()}")

    return built_quadrotor, visualizer



#calculate optimal trajectory and simulation
initial_state = [0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
# target state for trajectory optimization
final_state = [0., 3., 1, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
# limit of thrust force for each individual propellor
thrust_limit = 10.0

#we want to have an odd number
num_time_samples = 6
# number of samples into future we will run trajectory optimization
time_horizon = 6

#insantiate builder to connect high level system components
world_builder = DiagramBuilder()

# instatiate builder to build quadrotor by connecting MultiBodyPlant + Propellers
quadrotor_builder = DiagramBuilder()

# define world multibody plant containing quadrotor body and obstacles
world_plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(quadrotor_builder, time_step = 0.0)

# add obstacles to the simulated world
obstacles = []

####### Import .urdf files, connect quad body to propellers, connect geometry to scene graph
quadrotor_plant, visualizer = create_quadrotor(quadrotor_builder, world_plant, scene_graph, obstacles)

####### Add quadrotor to top level diagram builder #####
world_builder.AddSystem(quadrotor_plant)

# quadrotor_mutable_context = self.quadrotor_plant.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(self.sim_context)
quadrotor_context = quadrotor_plant.CreateDefaultContext()

# fix input port of quadrotor with output of MPC controller, in order to perform linearization
# this is the output from the previous iteration of the sim
quadrotor_plant.get_input_port(0).FixValue(quadrotor_context, [0.,0.,0.,0])

# input into the controller is the state of the quadrotor
# set the context equal to the current state
quadrotor_context.SetContinuousState(initial_state)


##################
# Linearize system dynamics - Take first order taylor series expansions of system
# around the operating point defined by quadrotor context
##################

linear_quadrotor = FirstOrderTaylorApproximation(quadrotor_plant, quadrotor_context)

#### get A & B matrices of linearized continuous dynamics
A = linear_quadrotor.A()
B = linear_quadrotor.B()



print(f"A = {A}")
print(f"B = {B}")
```

When I print the A & B matrices of the linearized dynamics, I see NaNs in the derivative terms

[image]

The NaN's in the derivative terms of the A & B matrices prevent trajectory optimization from being executed.

Could this issue be due to the way that I have declared the input / output ports of the `Spatial_Force_Concatinator`?

Or the way I have used the T wildcard to allow the `Spatial_Force_Concatinator` to accept different data types in Drake?

It seems unlikely to me that it is an issue with the force vector coming out of the `Propeller` class, as this class has probably been tested with a trajectory optimization problem before.

Comment: The `eq_check_tolerance = 10e6 # we do not need to be at an equilibrium point` is a red flag.  Prefer to use `FirstOrderTaylorApproximation` directly: https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__primitive__systems.html#ga14e2725af4ae2110baaf69555a49b591

Comment: If the problem was the way that you were using the T wildcard, I would expect you to get an error, not silent `NaNs`.  There is a lot of code here, but not enough for me to see exactly what `quadrotor_plant` you passed to the `MpcController`.  And I think a lot of the code is unnecessary for this problem.  If you can send a minimal *runnable* reproduction that just linearizes (no MPC necessary?) and gets NaNs, then it will be much easier to help.

Comment: I have edited the post to include a minimal runnable reproduction. I also linearized the dynamics using ```FirstOrderTaylorApproximation``` and observed the same result, with NaNs in the derivative terms of the A & B matrices.

Comment: thank you.  I'm able to reproduce it by changing the urdf line to
```
    quad_model= Parser(world_plant).AddModelFromFile(FindResourceOrThrow("drake/examples/quadrotor/quadrotor.urdf"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok.  This issue is actually real.  The equations of the wing compute the force using

```
fₙ = −ρ S (n ⋅ v) |v|
```

and you are evaluating the gradients at exactly `|v| = 0`, and our autodiff is giving NAN instead of a subgradient (e.g. zero). Note that if you set the velocity to anything non-zero, the NANs go away.

The standard fix is to implement one of the smoothed version of `|v|`; I will look into making that fix in Drake's Wing implementation now.

Comment: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/17127

Comment: Great, thanks for helping me out with this. To get around this I introduced some logic to that ensured wind velocities feeding in to the quadrotor plant could never equal 0. Values of 0 were replaced with 1e-9. Doing this allowed me to perform trajectory optimization successfully!

Comment: excellent.  fwiw -- the pull request with the fix has merged and it will be in tonight's nightly binaries.